# Add a custom CSS/JavaScript to the site's home modern page in a supported way

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am working on a modern team site >> and for the home page ONLY, i want to:-

- Hide the Site navigation bar, left-hand side navigation, page title and modify the float to remove the white space on the left-hand side
- Add a JavaScript to reload the page each 5 minutes.

to achieve the above I added the SharePoint modern script web part @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor and I added this custom CSS + custom JavaScript:-

```
<style>

#SuiteNavWrapper,#pageHeader, #spSiteHeader,#spLeftNav,#WebPart.PageTitle.internal.cbe7b0a9-3504-44dd-a3a3-0e5cacd07788
{
display:none;

}

div[data-automation-id="pageHeader"]
{
display:none;

}


#SuiteNavWrapper
{display:none !important ;}

.a_b_50a7110f:not(.b_b_50a7110f) {

    margin: 2px 0;
}


div[data-automation-id="CanvasZone"] > div:first-child
{max-width:100% !important;}

#customchart
{
    
    transform= "rotate(90deg)"; 
    display="inline-block";  
    
}

.root-95 {
height:10px;}
</style>

<script>

setInterval(function() {
                  window.location.reload(true);
                }, 300000); 
                
                

</script>
```

and it achieved what i am looking for.. but based on my reading that my above approach of adding modern script editor web part and inside it to add custom CSS/JavaScript is not supported.. so my question is how i can apply the above custom CSS/JavaScript in a supported way inside the home page? thanks in advance for any help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the top navigation bar, quick launch and page title using your own custom CSS is not supported. It can only be hidden using out of the box methods e.g. via a setting.

- The top navigation bar can not be hidden via a setting.
- The quick launch can be hidden by going to Site Settings > Navigation
  Elements and unticking the "Enable Quick Launch" option.
- To hide the page title, go to the home page > select the cog > Change
  the look > Header and deselect the "Site title visibility"
  option.
- The reloading of the page can be done via a SPFx extension, however I
  would not recommend doing this since it would probably cause a poor
  user experience.

**Update:** You can not hide top navigation, quick launch and page title for one page only using a setting. You can however add the URL parameter `?env=Embedded` to your URL and the page will be loaded without the header, quick launch and footer.

Comment: change the setting as you described will get applied to all the pages , while i want it to be for the home page only (as mentioned in my question) + i need to reload the page, because i am embedding some list views and those list views have custom formatting, and those custom formatting will not be applied unless we refresh the page, this is a limitation in list view formatting..

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: but adding `?env=Embedded` to the url will not achieve all the custom css i defined

Comment: Unfortunately, using custom CSS to hide the navigation elements is not supported as stated in my answer.

Comment: when you say it is not supported because the DOM elements might get changed in sharepoint,, but we can live with this fact and update the custom css accordingly...

Comment: It's not supported. I can't recommend that you do that.

Comment: I want to say that this is the ONE thing that EVERY SINGLE CUSTOMER has asked me for the last 15 years : "Please hide the side nav bar and the title on this single page". And it has ALWAYS been a massive headache : Setting? Applies to entire site (if you're lucky enough that you're not on a hub site where the visual settings are not controlled by the hub). Extension? Applies to whole site. Web part? Need extra permissions or not supported. IsDlg=1 or env=WebViewList or env=Embedded ? Doesn't work in some quick nav bar hyperlinks. Again: Every. Single. Customer for 15 years.